# Optimization of Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, primes, factors

Here is the [link](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e14a0058572a) to the problem.

The problem asks the number of solutions to the Diophantine equation of the form *1/x + 1/y = 1/z* (where *z = n!*). Rearranging the given equation clearly tells that the answer is the number of factors of *z<sup>2</sup>*.

So the problem boils down to finding the number of factors of *n!<sup>2</sup>* (*n* factorial squared).

My algorithm is as follows

1. Make a Boolean look up table for all primes <= n using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.
2. Iterate over all primes *P* <= *n* and find its exponent in *n!*. I did this using step function formula. Let the exponent be *K*, then the exponent of *P* in *n!<sup>2</sup>* will be *2K*.
3. Using step 2 calculate number of factors with the standard formula.

For the worst case input of *n = 10<sup>6</sup>*, my c code gives answer in 0.056s.
I guess the complexity is no way greater than *O(n lg n)*.
But when I submitted the code on the site, I could pass only 3/15 test cases with the verdict on the rest as time limit exceeded.

I need some hints for optimizing this algorithm.

Code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ULL unsigned long long int
#define MAXN 1000010
#define MOD 1000007

int isPrime[MAXN];

ULL solve(int N) {
    int i, j, f;
    ULL res = 1;
    memset(isPrime, 1, MAXN * sizeof(int));
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = 0;
    for (i = 2; i * i <= N; ++i)
        if (isPrime[i])
            for (j = i * i; j <= N; j += i)
                isPrime[j] = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (j = i, f = 0; j <= N; j *= i)
                f += N / j;
            f = ((f << 1) + 1) % MOD;
            res = (res * f) % MOD;
        }
    }
    return res % MOD;
}

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("%llu\n", solve(N));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm rather confident your sieve is way too slow. It shouldn't take anything near to 0.56 seconds to treat `n = 10^6`.

Comment: @MartinJames: I have added a link for my code.

Comment: @user1336893 : In the future, please edit the code directly into your question rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I mistyped the time for my code. Its 0.056s

Comment: @user1336893 That's much more reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the question btw, it was very interesting. I don't like all this negativity, the down-votes on questions, and that it was closed. You asked real qustion, got real advice (from Daniel :)).  Did you try the odds-only sieve, and did it help? BTW in C++, vector<bool> is automatically a bit-sieve, very convenient to use. :)

Comment: @WillNess: Nope, it did not help. I was aware of the points Daniel mentioned already. I will have to search for an algorithm with a better complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `int` overflow here:

```
for (j = i, f = 0; j <= N; j *= i)
```

If `46340 < i < 65536` and for many larger `i`, in the second iteration `j` will be negative if overflow wraps around (it is undefined behaviour, so anything could happen).

Replace it with e.g.

```
for(j = N / i, f = 0; j > 0; j /= i) {
    f += j;
}
```

It is, however, unlikely that the extra iterations due to the overflow would cause a "time limit exceeded", that will likely only cause wrong results.

So the generic advice is

- Sieve only odd numbers, perhaps also eliminate multiples of 3 from the sieve. Eliminating the odd numbers from the sieve roughly halves the time needed to sieve.
- Don't use an entire `int` for the flags, use bits or at least `char`s. That gives better cache locality and a further speedup.

Comment: It is a possible overflow. But I had the same code written in java first which had data type of j in step function loop as long (so no chances of overflow), then also in java to mark primes I used boolean array. I migrated to c because c is generally faster than java. 
Anyhow, there sure should be a overflow in c. 
Only option left is to use bits-sieve and 6K+1, 6K-1 optimization.

Comment: Is there any alternative/better approach to calculate factors of (n!)^2 ?

Comment: On my box, using `char isPrime[MAXN]` halved the running time, throwing out evens gave another factor of nearly 2, so 1 million finishes in ~5ms. Using a bit sieve brings it down to ~4ms. If the caches on the testing machines are small, using a bit-sieve would have larger impact. I am not aware of a better algorithm, the only thing I see is optimising the sieve. But for small limits as these, there's not much to be gained beyond leaving out multiples of 2 and 3.