# Adjust layout for 3 columns of common components with other components above/below

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I am building a simple GUI for a course assignment, but I am not getting the most out of it.

So this is my objective:[image]

And I am getting this (it lacks of some elements like the button):

[image]

So the thing is, **how do I code my layout to be tighter** like in the goal pic?

Code below:

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel{

    private JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    private JTextArea xTwin = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private JTextArea xCousin = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private JTextArea xSexy = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private JTextField getT = new JTextField(5);
    private JTextField getC= new JTextField(5);
    private JTextField getS = new JTextField(5);

    private JLabel cnstT = new JLabel("How many twin primes do you want?");
    private JLabel cnstC = new JLabel("How many cousin primes do you want?");
    private JLabel cnstS = new JLabel("How many sexy primes do you want?");
    private JLabel msgTwin = new JLabel("Area primes 'twin' created");
    private JLabel msgCousin = new JLabel("Area primes 'cousin' created");
    private JLabel msgSexy = new JLabel("Area primes 'sexy' created");  
    private JLabel msgGUI = new JLabel("GUI created");

    public Panel1(){
        xTwin.setEditable(false);
        xCousin.setEditable(false);
        xSexy.setEditable(false);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        p1.add(cnstT); p1.add(getT); p1.add(cnstC); p1.add(getC);
        p1.add(cnstS); p1.add(getS);
        p2.add(xTwin); p2.add(xCousin); p2.add(xSexy);
        p3.add(msgTwin); p3.add(msgCousin); p3.add(msgSexy);

        add(p1); add(p2); add(p3);
    }
```

Comment: For the 3 panels in the middle you might create a factory method that accepts a `String` (the type of randoms)  & potentially other things, like a `SpinnerNumberModel` - and returns a panel. Put those 3 panels in a single row `GridLayout`. Put that panel in the center of a `BorderLayout`. Add a panel to the `PAGE_START` with a `FlowLayout` for the button. Add a `JLabel` to the `PAGE_END` for the `GUI created` message. For more help, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your best attempt at implementing that approach.

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37885601/230513) below combines the factory and strategy patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code should help you to progress.

```
        public Panel1(){
            xTwin.setEditable(false);
            xCousin.setEditable(false);
            xSexy.setEditable(false);

            xTwin.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
            xCousin.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green));
            xSexy.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            buttonPane.add(cancel);
            this.add(buttonPane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);



            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

            p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel twinPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 
            twinPanel.add(cnstT);
            twinPanel.add(getT);
            p1.add(twinPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p1.add(xTwin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p1.add(msgTwin, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JPanel cousinPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 


            cousinPanel.add(cnstC);
            cousinPanel.add(getC);
            p2.add(cousinPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p2.add(xCousin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p2.add(msgCousin, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


            JPanel sexyPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 
            sexyPanel.add(cnstS);
            sexyPanel.add(getS);
            p3.add(sexyPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p3.add(xSexy, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p3.add(msgSexy, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            panel.add(p1);
            panel.add(p2);
            panel.add(p3);
        }
```

And this was the result.(Sorry about the borders)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! It's been a quite useful guide on how to use the different Java layouts. I was certainly lost about using the GridLayout and BorderLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Because the the panels differ only in name and function, use the [*strategy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222598/230513), to select the desired behavior at runtime. The example below illustrates an `enum`, each instance of which holds a display name and a function that takes an integer and returns a pair or integers: `Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>`. The actual functions used are placeholders; you can substitute one of the approaches seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10143431/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885601/230513
 */
public class StrategyTest {

    private enum Kind {
        TWIN((new Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<Integer, Integer> apply(Integer i) {
                return new Pair<>(i, i + 2);
            }
        })),
        COUSIN((new Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<Integer, Integer> apply(Integer i) {
                return new Pair<>(i, i + 4);
            }
        })),
        SEXY((new Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<Integer, Integer> apply(Integer i) {
                return new Pair<>(i, i + 6);
            }
        }));
        String dsiplayName;
        Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> function;

        private Kind(Function<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> function) {
            this.dsiplayName = name().toLowerCase();
            this.function = function;
        }
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(Kind kind) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.add(new JLabel("How many " + kind.dsiplayName + " primes?"));
        top.add(spinner);
        panel.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(16, 20);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Area for " + kind.dsiplayName + " primes.",
            JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        spinner.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
            int i = (int) spinner.getValue();
            Pair<Integer, Integer> p = kind.function.apply(i);
            textArea.append(p.getKey() + ":" + p.getValue() + "\n");
        });
        return panel;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("StrategyTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
        for (Kind kind : Kind.values()) {
            f.add(createPanel(kind));
        }
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new StrategyTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow @trashgod, that's a quite easy-to-use and straightforward layout configuration than the typical one. Even I'm not yet in the loop about SW design patterns it's very interesting to see it applied!

Comment: @flamenquino: As you pursue your studies, keep this pattern in mind when asked to compare two (or more) algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is located in the following line of code

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
```

The **GridLayout** is meant to divide the GUI into regions of the same size, which means, the embedded components do not have their natural size e.g. being stretched...

Use a different Layoutmanager instead! There are sevaral variants fitting to your needs...

For further information about the Layoutmanagers and their intended functionality, visit [this website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#set)

Comment: Yes, I did not have a clear concept about how the Java layouts distribute the components. Thanks a lot!